# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000

Tags: c++, массивы, строки, visual-c++, указатели

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Auto
{
    std::string Manufacturer;
    std::string TitleModel;
    std::string DateRelease;
    double Salary;
};

void print_menu();

void add_auto(Auto*, int*);

void search(Auto*);

int main() 
{
    int count_auto = 0;
    Auto *arr_auto = NULL;
    arr_auto = new Auto[10];
    while (true)
    {
        system("cls");
        print_menu();
        char MenuNum;
        std::cout << "Input menu number: ";
        std::cin >> MenuNum;
        switch (MenuNum)
        {
            case '1':
                add_auto(arr_auto, &count_auto);
                break;
            case '2': search(arr_auto);
                break;
            case '0': exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
                system("pause");
            break;
        }
    }
}

void print_menu() 
{
    std::cout << "------------------Menu------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Add auto;" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Search manufacturer;" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "0. Exit." << std::endl;
}

void add_auto(Auto *arr_auto, int *count_auto) 
{
    system("cls");
    if (*count_auto == (sizeof(arr_auto) / sizeof(arr_auto[0]))) 
    {
        Auto *temp = arr_auto;
        arr_auto = new Auto[(sizeof(arr_auto) / sizeof(arr_auto[0])) + 10];
        *arr_auto = *temp;
    }
    bool InputSuccess = false;
    std::string Manufacturer;
    std::string TitleModel;
    std::string DateRelease;
    double Salary;
    while (InputSuccess == false)
    {
        std::cout << "Input manufacturer: ";
        std::cin >> Manufacturer;
        std::cout << "Input title model: ";
        std::cin >> TitleModel;
        std::cout << "Input date release: ";
        std::cin >> DateRelease;
        std::cout << "Input salary: ";
        std::cin >> Salary;
        Auto auto_el;
        auto_el.Manufacturer = Manufacturer;
        auto_el.TitleModel = TitleModel;
        auto_el.DateRelease = DateRelease;
        auto_el.Salary = Salary;
        if (Manufacturer != "" && TitleModel != "" && DateRelease != "" && Salary > 0)
        {
            arr_auto[*count_auto + 1] = auto_el;
            *count_auto++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
            InputSuccess == false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Add success!" << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}

void search(Auto *auto_arr) 
{
    system("cls");
    std::string *Arr_manufacturer = new std::string[10];
    int CountManufacturer = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(auto_arr) / sizeof(auto_arr[0])); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(Arr_manufacturer) / sizeof(Arr_manufacturer[0])); j++)
        {
            if (Arr_manufacturer[j] == auto_arr[i].Manufacturer)
                continue;
            else
            {
                if (CountManufacturer == (sizeof(Arr_manufacturer) / sizeof(Arr_manufacturer[0])))
                {
                    std::string *Temp_manf = Arr_manufacturer;
                    Arr_manufacturer = new std::string[CountManufacturer + 10];
                    *Arr_manufacturer = *Temp_manf;
                }
                Arr_manufacturer[j] = auto_arr[i].Manufacturer;
                CountManufacturer++;
            }   
        }
    }
    int max = 0;
    std::string TempManufacturer = NULL;
    std::string MaxManufacturer = NULL;
    int AutoCount = 0;
    double SumSalary = 0;
    double srSalary = 0;
    bool isCheck = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(Arr_manufacturer) / sizeof(Arr_manufacturer[0])); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(auto_arr) / sizeof(auto_arr[0])); j++) 
        {
            if (Arr_manufacturer[i] == auto_arr[j].Manufacturer) 
            {
                isCheck = true;
                SumSalary += auto_arr[j].Salary;
                TempManufacturer = auto_arr[j].Manufacturer;
                AutoCount++;
            }
        }
        if (isCheck)
        {
            srSalary = SumSalary / AutoCount;
            if (max < srSalary)
            {
                max = srSalary;
                MaxManufacturer = TempManufacturer;
            }
            isCheck = false;
        }
        srSalary = 0;
        AutoCount = 0;
    }
    std::cout << "Max average salary = " << max << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Manufacturer: " << MaxManufacturer << std::endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Ошибка вылетает при вызове функции search(). Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0F7AF6E0 (ucrtbased.dll) в Task2.37.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.

Comment: Обычнейшее разыменование нулевого указателя

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум...
Чему, по-вашему, равно `(sizeof(auto_arr) / sizeof(auto_arr[0])`? Вообще-то скорее всего 0, потому что `sizeof(auto_arr)` - это размер указателя, максимум 8 байт в 64-разрядной программе, а `sizeof(auto_arr[0])` явно куда больше. И таких мест у вас никак не одно. Так что циклы ваши в `search` не работают ни разу, и получается примерно, выбрасывая лишнее и неработающее,

```
std::string MaxManufacturer = NULL;
std::cout << "Manufacturer: " << MaxManufacturer << std::endl;
```

Вот вам и ошибка чтения памяти...

Comment: что касается цикла, (sizeof(auto_arr) / sizeof(auto_arr[0])) = size array. Остальные циклы работают без проблем)

Comment: Выведите значения и проверьте. У вас нет ни  одного объявленного статически массива, так что вы неправы. Программирование - наука экспериментальная, вот и поставьте эксперимент... `auto_arr` у вас объявлен как `Auto *auto_arr`, а не как массив с определенным размером, так что `sizeof(auto_arr)` - размер указателя. Замечу вскользь - если это вам о чем-то говорит, что `sizeof` вычисляется во время компиляции, так что знать не знает (и не может), что вы там передаете...

Comment: Проверил, и правда ноль, Только вот решение от вас будет?)

Comment: Даже пару :) Например, передавайте этот размер как параметр в функцию. Или вместо массивов используйте `vector`, который свой размер точно знает и возвращает функцией-членом `.size()`.

Comment: да я бы работал с вектором, но мне бы хотелось это всё с динамическим массивом.

Answer (score 1):

Никогда не инициализируйте `std::string` через `NULL`, независимо от того, будете ли вы его потом заполнять чем-то другим, это должно вызвать `std::logic_error`, даже если ваш цикл до этого исправить на правильный, как справедливо указал Harry. Пишите просто `std::string TempManufacturer;`, это не Java, не всему можно присваивать `NULL`.

Также строчка `InputSuccess == false;`, наверное, подразумевала присваивание, но это сравнение, результат которого не используется.

И `std::string *Arr_manufacturer = new std::string[10];` без `delete []Arr_manufacturer` очень похоже на утечку памяти.

Comment: спасибо, убрал NULL и ошибки больше нет. Привык к шарпу :)

Comment: Тогда можно принять ответ, чтобы вопрос не оставался в незакрытых.